# How to paste a dynamic table from Excel to Word using the .Find function

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a project using VBA and it isn't a language I am  conformtable with.

I am trying to take all of my data in the spreadsheets and paste them to a word template using a `.Find` function that finds the appropriate tags.

It works until it gets to placing the final table at the end of the document after the Search finds the string its looking for. This is due to the table being dynamic and therefore will always have a different number of rows so it can't have a predefined table.

```
 If Len(Trim(.Cells(1, lCol))) <> 0 Then
    sSearch = .Cells(1, lCol)
    sSearch = "<<" & Trim(sSearch) & ">>"
    sTemp = .Cells(lRow, lCol)

    With oDocRange.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = sSearch
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting

        ' check - how to figure if string type?
        ' // If the cell text is > 255 then we get an error.
        ' // Calculate how many 'Chunks' of 250 are required to accomodate the long string.
        ' // If more than 1 chunk of text then we replace the original template
        ' // parameter with the first chunk and then insert additional parameters {2}, {3} etc
         ' // into the template and replace those with the additional chunks
        chunks = Round(Len(sTemp) / 250, 0)
        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, vbNewLine, vbCr) 
        sTemp = Replace(sTemp, Chr(10), vbCr)                          

        If sSearch = "<<Checklist>>" Then
           rng2.Copy            
           .Execute

           Set wrdTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=oDocRange, NumRows:=1, numColumns:=4)
           'With wrdTable
               'Selection.PasteAndFormat
               '.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
           'End With


           '.Execute FindText:="<<Checklist>>", ReplaceWith:=Selection, Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        End If

        If Len(sTemp) Mod 250 > 0 Then chunks = chunks + 1
        If chunks = 1 Then
           .Replacement.Text = sTemp
           .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
                 Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        Else
            .Execute FindText:=sSearch, ReplaceWith:="{1}", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            For i = 1 To chunks
               chunk = Mid(sTemp, ((i - 1) * 250) + 1, 250)
               If i < chunks Then chunk = chunk & "{" & (i + 1) & "}"
               .Execute FindText:="{" & i & "}", ReplaceWith:=chunk, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            Next i
        End If 'If chunks is > 0
    End With ' the oDocRange.Find
End If 'If the column value isn't blank
```

**sSearch** is what words the program is looking through the word document for. And I want it to find Checklist, and replace it with the table I have set as **rng2**.
In the `If` statement I have a bunch of failed attempts but it always comes back to a `"Type Mismatch" Error`.

Any help is greatly appreciated and I would be happy to give any more information. Thank you!

Comment: What happened when you used  `Selection.PasteAndFormat`. I see you have it there marked as a comment

Comment: Also, I take it that you have opened `Word` with your `Excel - VBA` script. Try just using `Selection.PasteAndFormat` because this is a `Word` function. And have you added the `Microsoft Office - Word Library` to your `Excel-VBA` project?

Comment: Hi Jean, when I used Selection.PasteAndFormat it came back as a Type Mismatch Error. And yes I have added the Word Library to the project as well.

Comment: Actually I was able to get the table to paste to the document finally using [oWord.Selection.PasteSpecial] but that only made it paste to the very top of the document since I have oDoc set as an Object  it references the beginning of the document and pastes it there. I need it to paste where the search runs into '<<Checklist>>' or at least at the bottom of the page instead.

Comment: Have you tried just using `Selection.PasteSpecial` otherwise try `oDocRange.Selection.PasteSpecial` because your search range is `oDocRange`

Comment: Using oDocRange gave me a Compile Error: "Method or data member not found" and then it highlighted Selection saying that's where the error was being made.

Comment: Did you try `Selection.PasteSpecial` otherwise replace oDocRange with oDoc in the string  I posted previously

Comment: Both Selection.PasteSpecial and oDoc.Selection.PasteSpecial came back as erros saying "Select Method of Range class failed"

Comment: Ok so what about after the sSearch is found then use `Selection.delete` to delete the text then try `Selection.PasteSpecial` it might be that it's moaning about pasting a table over the text

Comment: That would make sense, so would I just put sSearch.Selection.delete and then oDocRange.Selection.Paste?

Comment: Just oDoc before both selection

Comment: Using oDoc.Selection.Delete gave me the same error of "Object doesn't support this property or method" and it stopped the function before trying to PasteSpecial

Comment: Ok I will have to do some testing next week then. So you have an excel data sheet and you are opening Word via Excel and then searching Word for a string which is contained in a certain cell which you then paste a define group of cells from excel into word

Comment: The string I am searching for is not in a cell in word. It is just on a line at the top of the second page of my word template like so <<Checklist>>. and I just need it to replace that word with the table instead. Thanks!

Comment: Good stuff. Will have a look when I'm back at work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Error is because of the Excel.VBA script is getting used for Word.VBA script and visa versa.

The script below is a simple Excel.VBA script which opens a specific Word Document and then  searches for `sSearch` and then copies a range of Cells from Excel.

What I found was that I needed to reference each Application when I wanted to operate that Application. Example for Word I needed to use `Word.Selection` and for Excel `Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F13:)`

```
Sub SomeSubRoutine()

Dim WordProgram As Object
Dim WordFile As Object

WordFilePath = "Some File Path"

'Starting Word
Set WordProgram = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'Allowing it to be visible or not visible (For Developing its always good to have it visible
WordProgram.Application.Visible = True

'Opening the desired Word File
Set WordFile = WordProgram.Documents.Open(Filename:=WordFilePath)

'Here you can allocate your sSearch String
sSearch = "<<Checklist>>"

With Word.Selection.Find

    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<<Checklist>>" 'sSearch
   ' .Execute

    Do While .Execute
        If .Found = True Then

            Set EventData = Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F13")

            'Copying Event Log from the opened Excel File
            EventData.Copy

            With Word.Selection

                'Pasting Event Log into Word Doc
                .PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
                'Selecting the Table
                .Tables(1).Select
                'Horizontal Centering Text in the Table Rows
                .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                'Center Table to Page Center
                .Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
                'Vertical Centering of Text in the Table Row
                .Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalCenter
                'Moving out of the Table to continue search
                .MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdMove

            End With ' Ending "Word.Selection"

        Else

        'If nothing found then some other script can go here

        End If 'Ending "If .Found"

    Loop

End With ' Ending "Word.Selection.Find"

    'Quiting the Word Application
    WordProgram.Quit

    'clean up Objects for next use
    Set WordProgram = Nothing
    Set WordFile = Nothing

End Sub
```

Just check your referencing to each application for all your search.

Comment: Well done! Thanks so much for the help this has been driving me crazy for a couple weeks now. Being specific with my references got it to work.